# how to attach snapshot policy by label to all the vms in my project?

Tags: google-compute-engine, automation, snapshot, incremental-backup

I have created the snapshot schedule policy with label daily,weekly,hourly.But I want an automate way so whenever i create the vm label based policy should be assigned to vm. or

automatically attach my scheduler to vm disks whenver i create new vm and snapshot would save directly to bucket?

Is any one have the automate script for this task??

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach snapshot schedule policy to all VM's, you can run the below mentioned script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop through all disks within this project  and add snapshot schedule policy to all the VM’s
gcloud compute disks list | tail -n +2 | while read DISK_NAME ZONE c3 c4; do
gcloud compute disks add-resource-policies $DISK_NAME --resource-policies=ss-01 --zone $ZONE
done
```

However, If you want to automate snapshot schedule and snapshot create operation, you can follow the article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418427/how-to-create-and-rotate-automatic-snapshot).  At this moment, if you want to move the instance boot disk data to Google cloud storage, you can export a boot disk image to Cloud Storage as a tar.gz file that mention [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image).

Comment: Thanks mahboob  it works for me ! But as i get one more requirement for the same task...can we move this snapshots to storage bucket.  ? Is it possible to export the snapshot as i read the google documents i only found to export the images to bucket

Comment: You can export the snapshots to bucket, however, you are not able to export snapshots directly to the gcp bucket. Please follow the below steps to export snapshots to a bucket:

1- create image based on the snapshot 
2- create bucket and copy your bucket url then export your image with the following command
gcloud alpha compute images export --destination-uri gs://test_buk04/testimage.vmdk --image  expo-test-image --export-format vmdk --project yourprojectid

Answer (score 0):

You can export the snapshots to bucket, however, you are not able to export snapshots directly to the gcp bucket. Please follow the below steps to export snapshots to a bucket:

1. create image based on the snapshot
2. create bucket and copy your bucket url then export your image with the following command:

```
gcloud alpha compute images export --destination-uri gs://test_buk04/testimage.vmdk --image expo-test-image --export-format vmdk --project yourprojectid
```